# How to "Apply Edits" to an ArcGIS Server edit session using Python

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, editing

ArcGIS Server allows the user to apply edits in an editable layer.

Eg the sample layer at http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/3/applyEdits will accept a JSON input response such as `[{'attributes': {'distance':1234}}]`

Assuming that I have a JSON object in Python, how can I send this object to ArcGIS Server? ie, what is the Python syntax for Apply Edits?

I presume it's something along the lines of `urllib2.urlopen(<endpoint>, <JSON>)` but I can't figure out the exact syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax seems to work:

```
packet = {'attributes': {'distance': 12345}}
data = urllib.urlencode({'features': packet, 'f': 'pjson', 'rollbackOnFailure': True})
response = urllib2.urlopen(endPoint, data).read()
```

The result is:

```
[Dbg]>>> print(response)
{
  "addResults" : [
    {
      "objectId" : 12, 
      "globalId" : null, 
      "success" : true
    }
  ]
}
```